# Where is Icecat's plugins directory on GuixSD?

Tags: guix, gnu-icecat, guixsd

I want to try to add libflashplayer.so to Icecat. As it was on other distributions needs to add this file to plugins directory. But on GuixSD I have lot of them and nothing works!

So there each user has own set of applications in /gnu/store/hash-hash-hash floders. I copied libflashplayer.so to that directory `whereis icecat` showed and also to that another! that `ps aux| grep icecat` showed. Not helped.

```
$ whereis icecat
icecat: /gnu/store/r0y15j99qw6qr11m94n4agdfc7k4b3fx-profile/bin/icecat

$ cd /gnu/store/r0y15j99qw6qr11m94n4agdfc7k4b3fx-profile/
 /gnu/store/r0y15j99qw6qr11m94n4agdfc7k4b3fx-profile$ ls
bin/  etc/  include/  lib/  libexec/  manifest  sbin  share/

# mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda1 /gnu/store

# cp /home/user/Downloads/libflashplayer.so /gnu/store/r0y15j99qw6qr11m94n4agdfc7k4b3fx-profile/lib/mozilla/plugins/

# cd /gnu/store/r0y15j99qw6qr11m94n4agdfc7k4b3fx-profile/lib/mozilla/plugins/

# chmod 555 libflashplayer.so
```

.. flash plugin did not appear in icecat ..

```
$ ps aux | grep icecat
g          546 10.2  7.9 2137612 274108 ?      Sl   19:31   1:00 /gnu/store/rsw9m66npbnazx4b34xfdjyv6jqvrpsi-icecat-52.6.0-gnu1/bin/icecat
g          655  8.4  4.7 1841212 164176 ?      Sl   19:34   0:31 /gnu/store/rsw9m66npbnazx4b34xfdjyv6jqvrpsi-icecat-52.6.0-gnu1/lib/icecat-52.6.0/plugin-container -greomni /gnu/store/rsw9m66npbnazx4b34xfdjyv6jqvrpsi-icecat-52.6.0-gnu1/lib/icecat-52.6.0/omni.ja -appomni /gnu/store/rsw9m66npbnazx4b34xfdjyv6jqvrpsi-icecat-52.6.0-gnu1/lib/icecat-52.6.0/browser/omni.ja -appdir /gnu/store/rsw9m66npbnazx4b34xfdjyv6jqvrpsi-icecat-52.6.0-gnu1/lib/icecat-52.6.0/browser 546 tab
g          701  0.0  0.0   8260  1672 pts/2    S+   19:41   0:00 grep --color icecat


# mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda1 /gnu/store

# cp /home/user/Downloads/libflashplayer.so /gnu/store/rsw9m66npbnazx4b34xfdjyv6jqvrpsi-icecat-52.6.0-gnu1/lib/icecat-52.6.0

/gnu/store/rsw9m66npbnazx4b34xfdjyv6jqvrpsi-icecat-52.6.0-gnu1/lib/icecat-52.6.0# ls
application.ini  dependentlibs.list  gtk2/              liblgpllibs.so    libmozsandbox.so  plugin-container
browser/         dictionaries/       icecat             libmozavcodec.so  libxul.so         removed-files
chrome.manifest  fonts/              icecat-bin         libmozavutil.so   omni.ja           run-icecat.sh
defaults/        gmp-clearkey/       libflashplayer.so  libmozgtk.so      platform.ini
```

Not helped.

.. I have so many other icecat directories...

```
/gnu/store# find . -name icecat
./9glblfajzylgc3acvs00mvvf7pqy90hx-profile/bin/icecat
./dy3ivfy8yhmgai3rvjn1372yk0xy46cn-icecat-52.6.0-gnu1/lib/icecat-52.6.0/icecat
./dy3ivfy8yhmgai3rvjn1372yk0xy46cn-icecat-52.6.0-gnu1/bin/icecat
./30rclhg4hvyq0hczi3srabj791cyrx4y-profile/bin/icecat
./gm34i143bcyikqi83rjra23nay9yvv3l-profile/bin/icecat
./szfjspmjaip91rar72mq3rx1x9l5p3f8-profile/bin/icecat
./v78cwsbpl8nv9iqzjb8rpi5y5wgbf11n-profile/bin/icecat
./ig8yhn3i4fkr7dwbjlfjjyivmq56mh79-profile/bin/icecat
./gcw5b9gnfx3asy9kk2wva7q19zc8qmnm-profile/bin/icecat
./7n1d0c63jdfb3aafdzsw1gp5w3mnn3j2-profile/bin/icecat
./l8s46d8d9q6pkax4hcbdwjzsw4s9sp2n-profile/bin/icecat
./q7z68xlagis0rcwg816mf2msap0p2vfr-profile/bin/icecat
./4yx95c82pdfp67nba6gdhqgb9a4mbngd-profile/bin/icecat
./fqjcmap5yfd3870ai2qkghr4mq1rg9ma-profile/bin/icecat
./8vj84jsmw5bzh4prjx05f05xl4kk809q-profile/bin/icecat
./6sqhwknpavy7rnl67x5cy3rvm7420hr2-profile/bin/icecat
./cqgzk7agfv7wh91h6pms428vdj7wcjyb-profile/bin/icecat
./idz1699459i8495av4gxkkf2b3jdngki-profile/bin/icecat
./bq2c0p4bl18fh0fbd0zav0svnry9c60x-icecat-52.6.0-gnu1/lib/icecat-52.6.0/icecat
./bq2c0p4bl18fh0fbd0zav0svnry9c60x-icecat-52.6.0-gnu1/bin/icecat
./fan1w2c7kdrkdyhrwnjnriw389n3dy3d-profile/bin/icecat
./pv0isppwbhbpx6sdhwvkg9ddnib3irph-profile/bin/icecat
./6hd3lxhh8mlfnsv6ahd4wz014m33rcd2-profile/bin/icecat
./iwp89xlwn7bnblrrx3vsiiq8gm59r1vr-profile/bin/icecat
./lg45r1nsp1pb3zhh051nr23acpx2a1h3-profile/bin/icecat
./pg8wwm18bbglzarxbi92vyi1g7ifn7d8-profile/bin/icecat
./m02lxm92p7pzmhf7dmmn58miza98inp6-profile/bin/icecat
./czgs3d74agkd7i4fjj90phpkd0myr3d6-profile/bin/icecat
./34f36n0lg23kiykq2sx6p7j4jlxvz14i-profile/bin/icecat
./xdb121jz892lkiq9zd3v9rl60q44c3k0-profile/bin/icecat
./54c5sm8cj92saxn80jh5jr92mxa72440-profile/bin/icecat
./jvg9hd1lrnb7q4n6yd8parc12bp51n77-profile/bin/icecat
./rsw9m66npbnazx4b34xfdjyv6jqvrpsi-icecat-52.6.0-gnu1/lib/icecat-52.6.0/icecat
./rsw9m66npbnazx4b34xfdjyv6jqvrpsi-icecat-52.6.0-gnu1/bin/icecat
./b93whc8i26vkcmvh89blwmz5jh92k9xh-icecat-52.6.0-gnu1/lib/icecat-52.6.0/icecat
./b93whc8i26vkcmvh89blwmz5jh92k9xh-icecat-52.6.0-gnu1/bin/icecat
./pdmdhrqi3xllm5mlaqv8wk5400dqmza8-profile/bin/icecat
./0nfvxhmqj7vxark1bwwa4x5qqqf03czd-profile/bin/icecat
./pby1gzld8s2bbd9bs83vhmmhazgpbsql-profile/bin/icecat
./5km3ibyq3clwmzdgr3zx43rwa77gw5sd-profile/bin/icecat
./6f407nqnd87qaz1q1f4ydnb5sclr4jv9-icecat-52.6.0-gnu1/lib/icecat-52.6.0/icecat
./6f407nqnd87qaz1q1f4ydnb5sclr4jv9-icecat-52.6.0-gnu1/bin/icecat
./l1g1n415rvsp9vafcd19v2yqkn2yz9ns-icecat-52.6.0-gnu1/lib/icecat-52.6.0/icecat
./l1g1n415rvsp9vafcd19v2yqkn2yz9ns-icecat-52.6.0-gnu1/bin/icecat
./4ah8j8c98vz0jfi2n9xci7387r6afx3s-profile/bin/icecat
./9bbvxz62dc41nn6xh8q24dsq4dhxn3h1-profile/bin/icecat
./r6cqi1pw8wlf0yfz8rbcgby007xq0ysy-icecat-52.6.0-gnu1/lib/icecat-52.6.0/icecat
./r6cqi1pw8wlf0yfz8rbcgby007xq0ysy-icecat-52.6.0-gnu1/bin/icecat
./bqw3k6cv85hff2n9i96s0ds6kipzjfng-profile/bin/icecat
./r7fyy4lfbwbiqlwg6hmdpd2yfh0fwpcb-icecat-52.6.0-gnu1/lib/icecat-52.6.0/icecat
./r7fyy4lfbwbiqlwg6hmdpd2yfh0fwpcb-icecat-52.6.0-gnu1/bin/icecat
./srdm0rc203b7xrq27k4njjxvb236w7b4-profile/bin/icecat
./0walzaklznp3qnkvihc92ch3101gripm-profile/bin/icecat
./r0y15j99qw6qr11m94n4agdfc7k4b3fx-profile/bin/icecat
./7ql4wcxhk6fzwr0ydjfzciijp5bq62xs-icecat-52.6.0-gnu1/lib/icecat-52.6.0/icecat
./7ql4wcxhk6fzwr0ydjfzciijp5bq62xs-icecat-52.6.0-gnu1/bin/icecat
./jqqym4wcvl0aaq0h1nif722wayf98b0r-profile/bin/icecat
```

Where is that exact directory with icecat plugins for a certain user?

Comment: It could be in your home ~/.local or ~/.config